# What is the difference between RetryOptions and RequestRetryOptions?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-for-java

I am working with the Azure SDK for Java and specifically with blob storage and I am using the `SpecializedBlobClientBuilder`.

My question is around the various retry options:

```
SpecializedBlobClientBuilder retryOptions(RequestRetryOptions retryOptions)
SpecializedBlobClientBuilder retryOptions(RetryOptions retryOptions)
```

Initially I set `RetryOptions` on my client, but it did not seem to take effect in the case of a network timeout. However when I set `RequestRetryOptions` instead it does get applied and I am having trouble understanding why, what is the difference between these retry options and in which cases does `RetryOptions` actually get applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpecializedBlobClientBuilder` class provides options for configuring retries when interacting with Azure Blob Storage using Java.

1. **SpecializedBlobClientBuilder retryOptions(RequestRetryOptions retryOptions):**

As mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.specializedblobclientbuilder?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-specialized-specializedblobclientbuilder-retryoptions%28com-azure-storage-common-policy-requestretryoptions%29), `RequestRetryOptions` class allows to configure options specifically related to retrying individual HTTP requests made by SDK client.

[image]

- It is used for scenarios like network timeouts, connection failures, and other issues encountered while sending a request.
- If you set `RequestRetryOptions` on your client, it will affect the retry behavior of every request made through that particular client.

2. **SpecializedBlobClientBuilder retryOptions(RetryOptions retryOptions)**

As per [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.specializedblobclientbuilder?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-specialized-specializedblobclientbuilder-retryoptions%28com-azure-core-http-policy-retryoptions%29), this class is to configure retry policy for SDK client related to retrying higher-level operations and it handles retries at the operation level, which involve multiple HTTP requests

[image]

- If you set `RetryOptions` on your client, it will affect the retry behavior for higher-level operations.

---

- To configure the retry policy for HTTP requests made by the client, use the `RequestRetryOptions` class.
- To configure the retry policy for the client, use `RetryOptions` class.
- Both `RequestRetryOptions` and `RetryOptions` are mutually exclusive. So, it is better to consider both classes while configuring storage options.

**References:**

Refer to the [github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/main/java/com/azure/storage/blob/specialized/SpecializedBlobClientBuilder.java) for sample code to understand `SpecializedBlobClientBuilder`, `RetryOptions` and `RequestRetryOptions`.

Comment: "Both RequestRetryOptions and RetryOptions are mutually exclusive. So, it is better to consider both classes while configuring storage options." --> mutually exclusive usually means that you cannot set both at the same time. So it is actually unclear how to set both retry behaviours.

Comment: Based on my reading of the Azure SDK code, this answer is incorrect. Nothing in the code suggests that the two retry options act on different layers. Can you show the code that would back your interpretation? See also my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77259149/3552141

Answer (score 0):

This is the [relevant code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/2507e3494d70eba6f6f90f9bb4bbe46e3c35ecec/sdk/storage/azure-storage-common/src/main/java/com/azure/storage/common/implementation/BuilderUtils.java#L19) that builds the retry policy in the Azure SDK:

```java
    public static RequestRetryPolicy createRetryPolicy(
        RequestRetryOptions retryOptions, RetryOptions coreRetryOptions, ClientLogger logger) {
        if (retryOptions != null && coreRetryOptions != null) {
            throw logger.logExceptionAsWarning(
                new IllegalStateException(
                    "'retryOptions(RequestRetryOptions)' and 'retryOptions(RetryOptions)' cannot both be set"));
        }
        if (coreRetryOptions != null) {
            retryOptions = RequestRetryOptions.fromRetryOptions(coreRetryOptions, null, null);
        }
        if (retryOptions == null) {
            retryOptions = new RequestRetryOptions();
        }
        return new RequestRetryPolicy(retryOptions);
    }
```

You can see that the `RequestRetryOptions` seem to be the "master class" from which the retry policy gets built.

If instead the `RetryOptions` get passed, then from that the derived `RequestRetryOptions` is built, with some default values.

Based on this, if in doubt, I would use the `RequestRetryOptions`, because these are the options actually directly used in the retry policy.

But also looking at the Azure SDK code, I don't see anywhere anything that would suggest that the other options don't apply e.g. to network timeouts. Maybe that was some other effect that you observed, unrelated to the retry option config?